# Можно ли составлять запросы типа INSERT ... JOIN?

Tags: mysql, запрос, insert

Есть таблица, в которую мне нужно вставить значения. Она связана по полю `paramID` с другой, справочной таблицей. На тот момент, когда мне нужно вставить значение в первую таблицу, мне известно имя параметра из второй таблицы, но неизвестно его `paramID`.

```
PRICE                              REF_BOOK

|  id  |  paramID  |  value  |     |  paramID  |  pName  |
|------|-----------|---------|     |-----------|---------|
```

Всё, что мне пока пришло в голову, это:

```
INSERT INTO price (paramID, value)
VALUES 
    ((SELECT paramID FROM ref_book WHERE pName = 'param1' LIMIT 1), 1),
    ((SELECT paramID FROM ref_book WHERE pName = 'param2' LIMIT 1), 2),
    ((SELECT paramID FROM ref_book WHERE pName = 'param3' LIMIT 1), 3)
```

Есть ли способ быстрее / оптимальнее? Или проще сделать заранее выборку из `ref_book`, перебрать массив и заменить все имена на индексы строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И в вопросе и в ответе повторяются слова про `JOIN` но, почему-то его так и не используют для вставки данных.

Судя по тому, что таблица `REF_BOOK` справочная - я могу предположить, что все данные в ней уже есть и в нее вставлять ничего не надо.

Я не знаю в каком виде находятся те данные, которые нужно вставить в таблицу `PRICE`, поэтому оформлю их в виде подзапроса. 
Если использовать `JOIN` то получится примерно так (полный пример [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7515e/1)):

```
insert into price (paramId, propId, value)
select rf.paramId, p.propId, t.value
from 
(
  select 'param1' pName, 'prop3' propName, 10 value union all
  select 'param2', 'prop2', 20 union all
  select 'param3', 'prop1', 30 
) t
join ref_book rf on rf.pName = t.pName
join prop p on p.propName = t.propName
```

Comment: В вопросе был JOIN  в контекста "а можно ли?". Вложенным SELECT я показал, чего хочу достичь. Но ух, это отлично. Сложновато для начала, но это именно то. ) А псевдонимы только у первого селекта (во втором уровне) - это потому что UNION ALL?

Comment: Да, в `UNION ALL` псевдонимы можно указывать только для первого запроса. Более того, любые псевдонимы для последующих запросов в конструкции `UNION ALL` будут просто проигнорированы, т.к. `UNION ALL` опирается на порядок колонок, а не на их название.

Answer (score 3):

Синтакс `INSERT .... JOIN` невозможен.
Есть вариант `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN`, но он Вам не нужен.

В вашем случае надо сначала внести все данные в `REF_BOOK`. И уже повторяющимися запросами заносить информацию в `price`.

Что-то типа такого:

```
INSERT INTO REF_BOOK (pName) VALUES ('param1'), ('param2'), ('param3');
INSERT INTO price (paramID, value) SELECT paramID, '1' FROM REF_BOOK WHERE pName='param1';
INSERT INTO price (paramID, value) SELECT paramID, '2' FROM REF_BOOK WHERE pName='param2';
INSERT INTO price (paramID, value) SELECT paramID, '3' FROM REF_BOOK WHERE pName='param3';
```

Теоретически можно сделать `INSERT INTO price` одним запросом. Но будет очень громоздко и не очень удобно для большого кол-ва параметров. Вобщем не советовал бы... Лучше по одному.

Comment: А если усложнить вопрос, и связать нужно сразу три справочных таблицы, к примеру? `INSERT INTO price (subpriceID, paramID, propID, value) ...` то для каждого ..ID свой `SELECT ... WHERE` через запятую?

Comment: Да, придется.   
Если `value` - это какое-то фиксированное значение, то придется... Если же у Вас все данные, что надо вставить, хранятся в базе, то можно сделать `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` одним запросом.   
Но чтобы точно сказать, нужны детали... структура и т.д.